# Passing a numeric parameter from a method to be appended after 'top' or 'first' like : findTop[paramValue]By

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm wondering if it is possible to pass a parameter to the jpa data methods

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
private @Id
@GeneratedValue
Long id;
private String name;
private String dept;
private int salary;
.............
}


public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> 
{

  List<Employee> findTop3ByOrderBySalaryDesc();

}
```

Pass the limit as a parameter insteed of write :

```
   List<Employee> findTop3ByOrderBySalaryDesc();
```

i want to write a generic method like this and pass the myLimit as a param:

```
   List<Employee> findTop<myLimit>ByOrderBySalaryDesc();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding a `Pageable` argument to the method and removing the `Top` part of the query. 
The `Pageable` should also carry the information what is sorted by.
So you end up with:

```
List<Employee> findBy(Pageable limit)
```

To make it look nicer you may construct a static method constructing the `PageRequest`

```
static Pageable topSalaries(int limit) {
    return PageRequest(0, limit, DESC, "salary");
}
```

So invoking it would look like:

```
findBy(topSalaries(5));
```